# Attempts to connect to an API endpoint result in inability to connect to localhost

Tags: node.js, rest, express, axios, postgresql-9.3

I have an App which retrieves a random statement from a postgres table when a button is clicked:

```
getRandomQuote() {    

 axios.get('http://localhost:3100/quote').then(response => {

    console.log('1111111', response);

    this.setState( 
      {
        quote: response.data[0].quote_text,
        quoteAuthor: response.data[0].author,
        opacityZero: false
      } );
      setTimeout(_=>this.setState( {opacityZero: true} ),100)
  })
}
```

However, when I click the button while running the app, I receive the result:

```
GET http://localhost:3100/quote net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

along with

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
at createError (createError.js:16)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:87)
```

Attempting to go to http://localhost:3100/quote in the chrome browser delivers me to "This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED". For the time being I don't seem to have a reason to believe that this issue is the result of my express server or database as far as I know, since the primary issue seems to be its inability to connect to a localhost endpoint.

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http');
var massive = require('massive');
const cors = require('cors');

var connectionString = 'postgres://myname@localhost/quotedatabase'; 
console.log('getting here');
app.use(cors());
massive(connectionString).then(db => {
  app.set('db', db);
  http.createServer(app).listen(3100);
  console.log('getting here two');
}) 

var db = app.get('db');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('a little short yeah? ask for a quote');
});  

app.get('/quote', function(req, res) {
  var db = app.get('db');

  db.getRandomQuote().then(randomQuote => {
      console.log(randomQuote);
      res.send(randomQuote);
  }).catch(console.log)
})
```

Comment: So, this is likely an issue on your localhost server.  I think we need to see that.  You can also try restarting Chrome and/or restarting your computer.

Comment: @jfriend00 Added the server.js above.

Comment: How you're creating two separate servers, one with `app.listen()` and one with `http.createServer()`.  One of those only, please.

Comment: @jfriend00 I tried the solution below, and it didn't fix it. I'll be sticking with `http.createServer()`. I still get the following errors in console when clicking the "get quote" button:

    `GET http://localhost:3100/quote 
    net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED xhr.js:178`

and

   ` Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16) 
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:87)`

Comment: Do you know for sure that `massive(connectionString).then()` is succeeding.  You should put a `.catch()` on that and log there in case that is not succeeding.  Because if it's not succeeding, then you will never start your server and never log anything either.

Comment: @jfriend00 I've added this to server.js:
`massive(connectionString).then(db => {
  app.set('db', db);
  http.createServer(app).listen(3100);
  console.log('getting here two');
}).catch(function(error) {console.log(error)
}); `

the console still isn't indicating what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

This means you can't connect to your server. Indeed you need to make the server listen on a port using `app.listen(port)`

http://expressjs.com/fr/4x/api.html#app.listen

Comment: I added a `app.listen(3100);`. Do I need that in addition to the 
`http.createServer(app).listen(3100);` ? I'm still getting 
`xhr.js:178 GET http://localhost:3100/quote net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`
along with
`Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:87)`

Comment: You can only have one of these. Remove the http server and only keep your express app

Answer (score 0):

I should've run `nodemon server.js` in the directory of my api instead of the app's directory root.